# How can I remove filters from custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, the-content, filters

I created a custom post type which I'll use as landing page for PPC. Now on that custom post type I would like to remove all the filters which are adding the social media buttons for example. I tried already with the following code but that did also remove the shortcode filter which I would like to keep on that custom post type. Here's the code I used:

```
    function landingpage_remove_plugin_filters() {

    global $wp_filter;
    global $wp;
    if ($wp->query_vars["post_type"] == 'landingpage') {
    remove_all_filters('the_content', 'plugin_filters');
    }
    }   

    add_action('wp','landingpage_remove_plugin_filters');
```

Does anyone know what I need to change in order to keep the shortcode filters on that custom post type?

Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try re-adding the 'do_shortcode' filter like so:

```
function landingpage_remove_plugin_filters() {

    global $wp_filter;
    global $wp;
    if ($wp->query_vars["post_type"] == 'landingpage') {
        remove_all_filters('the_content', 'plugin_filters');
        add_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode');
    }
}   

add_action('wp','landingpage_remove_plugin_filters');
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I should have thought of that myself :-)

Comment: Good to hear it. Could you mark the answer as accepted so that everyone knows this question has been solved?

Answer (score 0):

`remove_all_filters` function removes all of the hooks from filter, and it only has two parameters `$tag` ( the filter to remove hooks from ) and `$priority`

if you want to remove all hooks from filter use `remove_all_filters`, but if you only want to remove hook named `plugin_filters` use `remove_filter` function

```
function landingpage_remove_plugin_filters() {
    global $post;

    if ( 'landingpage' == $post->post_type )
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'plugin_filters' );
}
add_action( 'wp', 'landingpage_remove_plugin_filters' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your code too but it didn't remove the filters I wanted. I still got the social share buttons showing up.

Comment: What plugin do you use for social sharing?

Comment: I tested that with several plugins. One of them was: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-facebook-google-plusone-share/

Comment: In which file should I put this function? I would like to `remove_all_filters("the_content")`

Comment: @qed It can be custom plugin or functions.php.